# make variable available in all method of controller when passed in one method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here i send the user.id as params dd

```
<h3><%= link_to("Lend Asset", {:controller => 'empassets', :action=> 'index', :dd => user.id})%></h3>
```

In controller empassets i fetch it by

```
  def index
     @id = params[:dd]
     @empassets = Empasset.where(:ad => @id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @empassets }
    end
  end

  def show
     @id = params[:dd]
    @empasset = Empasset.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @empasset }
    end
  end

  def new
     @id = params[:dd]
    @empasset = Empasset.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @empasset }
    end
  end

  def edit
     @id = params[:dd]
    @empasset = Empasset.find(params[:id])
  end
```

I need this @id in all new show edit method. But it takes in index only as i mention it in index. How can i make such that if Lend asset is click then @id= params[:id] have value in all methods. How can it is possible to make it available for another @id = params[:id] is not send in that controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe will be better if you store the current user in session and after that, capture the user model with a filter in the controller, like this:

```
# controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_current_user_in_model

  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(params[:dd]) || User.new
  end

  # This method save the current user in the user model, this is useful to have access to the current user from a model and not from the controller only
  def set_current_user_in_model
    User.current_user current_user if not current_user.nil?
  end
end

# models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  # This is useful to get the current user inside a model
  def self.current_user(user = nil)
    @@current_user = (user || @@current_user)
  end
  #...
end
```

Basically, my idea is store that information inside a model with a filter, you can use session if you wanth to get the information (user id).

```
def index
  session[:user_id] = params[:dd]
  @empassets = Empasset.where(:ad => session[:user_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @empassets }
  end
end

def show
  @empasset = Empasset.find(session[:user_id] || params[:dd])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @empasset }
  end
end
```

Note I used `session[:user_id] || params[:dd]` because maybe, the session information was not stablished and you give it `:dd` parameter. But if you want to stablish the `@id` variable, you can use a filter like before.

But I don't know what is the main problem.

**Edit**

```
# controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_dd_param, :except => :index
  def index
    session[:dd] = params[:dd] # Here you write the session
    @current_user ||= User.find(params[:dd]) || User.new
  end
  # ...
  protected
  def set_dd_param
    params[:dd] = session[:dd] || -1 # Here you read the session a write the params variable
  end
end
```

Sorry for the delay.

Comment: I appreciate for your answer.. It is really close for my question. Admin is logeed in then it view the users <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
     
      <h3><%= link_to("Lend Asset", {:controller => 'empassets', :action=> 'index', :dd => user.id})%></h3>
      <h3><%= link_to("Return Asset", {:controller => 'empreassets', :action=> 'index', :dd => user.id})%></h3>    From here with id of that user it have to enter to the other controller But that id shoul be available to all methods inside controllers As all the data created by that controler shoulb contain that id.

Comment: Is it possible to make available params[:dd] in all method to that controller until another params[:dd] is not send in that controller? If possible then my problem will be solved..

Comment: You can add a `before_filter` and rewrite the param dd, like `params[:dd] = session[:dd] || -1`, this way, if `session[:dd]` is stablish, `params[:dd]` have the same value, if not, the value is `-1`.

Comment: Can u edit this in your answer above so that i get it clearly. I am messed up.. Thanks for your help. I think i get it. Since i have less knowledge of session i feel difficult. It should be like this unless new params[:dd] is not sent old one should be used

Comment: I have current user already Admin. Now admin have to edit other employee things But for this here i send the user id and in controller that user id is needed such that in every action until i send other userid the session should be that id. But when i return back to index then id becomes -1. Have to function such that In that controller there should be that params[:dd] in all method as it is required to find the data related to that id and in submit also that id is needed. so It is needed in some controller so better to edit this in empassets controller so that it can work in show edit new.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to store it to the session, there is no way to automatically make @id available to every method in the controller.. but you can add the param to each link/form, like so:

```
<%= link_to("New Asset", {:controller => 'empassets', :action=> 'new', :dd => @id})%>

<%= link_to("Show Asset", {:controller => 'empassets', :action=> 'show', :dd => @id})%>
```

where these links are in the index view and `@id` is set in the index method.

Not exactly sure what the goal is here, but something like this may work.

Comment: I mean how to make globally capture that id which is send to index? It means u send it to index. But later when u use show or edit method still u can use that id in these methods. If possible how can i store that in session so that it can be used in other method also?

Answer (score 0):

```
def index
 $id = params[:dd]
 @empassets = Empasset.where(:ad => @id)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @empassets }
end
```